# While loop break condition not working

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to read a file, which will break when gets a line starting with `"--------------------------"` as:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
def cinpt():
    with open("test", 'r') as finp:
        for line in finp:
            if line.strip().startswith("start"):
                while not line.startswith("---------------"):
                    sdata = finp.readline()
                    print(sdata.strip())

cinpt()
```

a demo input file(`test`) is:

```
foo
barr
hii
start
some
unknown 
number 
of
line
-----------------------------
some 
more 
scrap
```

I am expecting the code to break after reading line `"line"`. The expected output is:

```
some
unknown 
number 
of
line
```

it takes `start` condition properly but not breaking at "----", instead goes to an infinite loop. What I am getting is:

```
some
scrap
line
-----------------------------
some
more
scrap
```

Comment: Your `while` loop is inside of your `for` loop. That while loop runs every time the for loop runs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It loops forever because your line variable does not change during the while loop. You should iterate line by line, its simple.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
def cinpt():
    with open("test", 'r') as finp:
        started = False
        for line in finp:
            if started:
                if line.startswith("---------------"):
                    break
                else:
                    print(line.strip())
            elif line.strip().startswith("start"):
                started = True

cinpt()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read the liens form your file in a  single place 
As it is, you are fetching lines from your file both at  `for  line in finp:` line and at `sdata = finp.readline()` - this likely will be bad for you (as you have found out).

Keep your fiel data in a  single place, and use auxiliar state variables to know how you should deal with that data. #!/usr/bin/python3

```
def cinpt():
    with open("test", 'r') as finp:
        inside_region_of_interest = False
        for line in finp:
            if line.strip().startswith("start"):
                inside_region_of_interest = True
            elif  line.startswith("---------------"):
                inside_region_of_interest = False
            elif inside_region_of_interest:
                sdata = line
                print(sdata.strip())

cinpt()
```

That said, your particular problem is that even though your `while` condition is on the `line` variable, you never modify *that* variable inside your while loop. Its content remains fixed at `"start\n"` up to the end of the file.